# Is there any evidence to suggest telling puns to a child makes them enjoy it when they are older?

Tags: developmental-psychology, conditioning, humour

My own experience was that my father and grandfather retold many puns as I was in my childhood and teens; at the time, I thought it was abysmal.

Now I think they're the funniest things ever.

**Is there any evidence to suggest that telling puns to children makes them enjoy those puns when they are older?** I.e., are puns 'conditioned'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nostalgia for fond memories commonly produces positive emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostalgia#As_a_comfort) (for further review, see [Zhou, Wildschut, Sedikides, Chen, & Vingerhoets, 2012](http://www.wildschut.me/Tim_Wildschut/home_files/emo-2012-05385-001.pdf)). As for the increase in your appreciation of these particular puns, I've mentioned in [a very recent answer of mine to another very recent question about humor](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/5626/4086) that positive emotion alone may encourage the sense that something is funny. Depending on the nature of the particular puns, they might also appeal to a certain sense of humor you've had to develop with age and experience.

<sub>This last point is just conditional speculation though; I also admit that the article I've cited doesn't pertain to humor directly, and I can't provide more direct evidence of the sort your question requests offhand. I hope someone else can!</sub>

**Reference**

Zhou, X., Wildschut, T., Sedikides, C., Chen, X., & Vingerhoets, A. J. (2012). Heartwarming memories: Nostalgia maintains physiological comfort. *Emotion, 12*(4), 678–685. Available online, URL: http://www.wildschut.me/Tim_Wildschut/home_files/emo-2012-05385-001.pdf.