# What makes a sight or an image mesmerizing and irresistible?

Tags: attention

There are some examples of this.

What makes us:

- Feel we just HAVE TO watch that video or an image again, it's common with comedy videos
- Feel we need to stare at a such a beautiful sight, a person or an image

It's not that something is particularly interesting to the conscious mind, but yet we still can't resist but watch.

What's the science behind this process?

Comment: Could you provide some of those examples?

Comment: Posting a comedy video or a beautiful woman's picture wouldn't be appropriate. I think the description was clear.

Comment: You don't have to post them to describe them more specifically, but I don't think it would be inappropriate to offer links as far as the site is concerned. It's only unclear how you intend to exclude conscious interest (and what initial research you've done, if any). Otherwise as is, this is a very broad question, so it's hard to imagine where an answer should begin, let alone end...Nonetheless, I've got a simple idea I can offer in case you're not looking for an especially deep answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the encyclopedic issue of what might make an unspecified stimulus funny, beautiful, or otherwise pleasing for its [aesthetics](/questions/tagged/aesthetics), it's at least evident that you're asking about [reinforcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement) stimuli that provide [incentives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incentive) via [emotion](/questions/tagged/emotion)al [reward(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reward_%28psychology%29#Psychological_reward). It's not clear how you expect to rule out conscious interest, but reinforcement learning may not necessitate consideration of conscious control, so I suppose we can disregard the whole issue of [consciousness](/questions/tagged/consciousness) at this level of generality (or ambiguity/vagueness). That is essentially the approach of [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_behaviorism) [behaviorism](/questions/tagged/behaviorism), after all.

Aside from the tags and links included so far, there's plenty of science available on psychological reward:

- Relevant neural structures include the [ventral tegmental area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventral_tegmental_area#Reward_system) and [nucleus accumbens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleus_accumbens#Pleasure_and_reinforcement).
- [Dopamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine#Reward) is probably the most relevant [neurotransmitter](/questions/tagged/neurotransmitter), but other [catecholamines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catecholamine) such as [adrenalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine#Epinephrine_and_psychology) and [norepinephrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine#Decision_making) may affect impulse regulation and attention.
- Relevant [personality](/questions/tagged/personality) factors include the [behavioral activation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_activation_system#Behavioral_Activation_System) and [sensation-seeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking). Other factors become more or less relevant depending on the nature of the stimulus, e.g.:

  - [Openness to experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openness_to_experience) affects aesthetic preferences, especially in art and culture.
  - Cultural background affects interests, preferences, and incentives through [taste acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquired_taste).
  - [Emotional stability and extraversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arousal#Introversion_and_extraversion) may affect [attitudes](/questions/tagged/attitudes) toward arousing or social stimuli.
  - [Sexual desire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_desire#Theoretical_perspectives) may be relevant, depending on the stimulus and the individual.
  - Emotional and physiological states affect the strength and relevance of other needs / motives.
  - [Conscientiousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness) or control affects impulse regulation, which is relevant if urge resistance is.
- We have a dedicated question about humor: [How does our brain consider something to be funny?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5625/4086)